# Limit of a complex valued function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

> Consider the complex valued function given by
>   $$f(z)=\frac { \operatorname{Re}(z)+\operatorname{Im}(z)}{|z|^2}.$$
>   Does $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)$  exists?

This is how I approached the problem-

Consider $z \in \Bbb {C}$ , then $z$ must be of the form $z=x+iy$.
$\operatorname{Re}(z)=x$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)=y$ and $|z|^2=x^2+y^2$
As $z\rightarrow 0, (x,y)\rightarrow (0,0) $.

So we have $$\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{x+y}{x^2+y^2}$$

Evaluating limit along the path $y=mx$ and with easy simplification we have 
$$\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1+m}{x(1+m^2)}=\infty $$

Is the above approach correct? If yes, then do I say that the limit does not exist or do I say that limit exists and $\lim_{z\to 0} f(z)=\infty$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approche is good, but the result is not. 
Indeed, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x}{x^2+x^2}=\frac{1}{x}=\begin{cases}+\infty &x>0\\ -\infty &x<0,\end{cases}$$
and thus the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay so we conclude that the limit does not exist because its value isn't unique. What if the limit would have had a unique value (say) +infinity? Then in this case what would the conclusion be?

Comment: @AbhishekBhat: I don't understand your question ? You mean if $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x+x}{x^2+x^2}$ exist ?

Comment: I am asking the following question in a general context and not in the view of the above problem. In general if the value of the limit is infinity, then can we say the limit exists and its value is infinity? or do we say limit does not exist(since its value is infinity)?

Comment: If it's infinity, the limit doesn't exist. But you can differentiate the fact that $f$ diverge to $+\infty $ and the fact that the limit doesn't exist at all.

Comment: That was helpful. Thank You!